# How to extend javascript editor in JSDT in Eclipse with adding new functions

Tags: javascript, editor, eclipse-rcp

I am using RCP to create special javascripts editor with special functions and want to extends js editor from JSDT by adding new functions in context menu and in content assistant. But how can I start. Here is my thinking:
 1) rewrite a jscript editor which extends CompilationUnitEditor by import org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor; But it seems not working, it only has part of functions from JSDT, no colored squiggly marks in the text.

```
import org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor;

public class Jscript extends CompilationUnitEditor {

    public static final String ID="com.test.scripteditor.editor3";
    public Jscript(){
            super();        
    }   
}
```

2) Any possibles ways to add exentsions directly from plugin.xml to make this process quick?

Thanks for any suggestions. I do really do not know how to do it.