# Content assist for Eclipse JSDT based Editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, content-assist, jsdt, nodeclipse

In Eclipse content assist is usually implemented by some class that `implements IContentAssistProcessor` ([JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fcontentassist%2FIContentAssistProcessor.html), [example](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/contentassist/NodeContentAssistant.java))

**How to implement the same `CompletionProposal`s for JSDT based Editor?**

The only example I know is http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/ , but it is large and unclear how to extend JSDT for code assist.

Are there other APIs in JSDT? Please point to APIs to use.

Related
[How to extend javascript editor in JSDT in Eclipse with adding new functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294199/how-to-extend-javascript-editor-in-jsdt-in-eclipse-with-adding-new-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the [completion proposal extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html) of the JSDT editor.
 In there you have to specify a class implementing the necessary interface, but it is a different one than the very generic IContentAssistProcessor.

Depending on your use case you may also want to have a look at the related [quickAssist](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_quickAssistProcessors.html?cp=31_4_2_19) and [quickFix](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_quickFixProcessors.html?cp=31_4_2_20) extension points.

Comment: Thanks for help, you did led me to right place.
I stumbled over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779899/content-assist-for-eclipse-jsdt-based-editor-gives-no-proposal