# Content assist with javaCompletionProposalComputer for Eclipse JSDT gives no proposal

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, content-assist, jsdt, nodeclipse

Content assist with `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` for Eclipse JSDT gives no proposal.

In `Preferences -> JavaScript -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced`
"Nodeclipse Proposals" are visible, and selected.

as advised by Bananaweizen to [Content assist for Eclipse JSDT based Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738788/content-assist-for-eclipse-jsdt-based-editor)

in plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
   id="nodeclispe_textual_proposals"
   name="Nodeclipse Text Proposals">
   <proposalCategory icon="icons/npm/npm.gif"/>
 </extension>
 <extension point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
   id="NodeclipseProposals"
   name="Nodeclipse Proposals">
   <javaCompletionProposalComputer
      class="org.nodeclipse.ui.contentassist.JSDTProposalComputer"
      categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.textual_proposals">
      <partition type="__java_javadoc"/>
   </javaCompletionProposalComputer>
 </extension>
```

`JSDTProposalComputer` is just wrapper for `NodeContentAssistant`
(that implements `IContentAssistProcessor`), that works perfectly well for TextEditor based Editor.

```
public class JSDTProposalComputer implements IJavaCompletionProposalComputer {

    IContentAssistProcessor assistant = new NodeContentAssistant();

    @Override
    public List<ICompletionProposal> computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        return Arrays.asList(assistant.computeCompletionProposals(context.getViewer(), context.getInvocationOffset()));
    }

    @Override
    public List<IContextInformation> computeContextInformation(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        return Arrays.asList(assistant.computeContextInformation(context.getViewer(), context.getInvocationOffset()));
    }
```

examples from [help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html) are

- HippieProposalComputer - http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/internal/ui/text/java/HippieProposalComputer.java
- HippieProposalProcessor - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5.2/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/texteditor/3.5.1/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/HippieProposalProcessor.java

All code is on GitHUb `contentassist` package https://github.com/Enide/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/contentassist

Comment: search for <partition type="__java_javadoc"/> on http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp gived no results, but on Juno http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp returns "JavaScript Completion Proposal Computer" & "Java Completion Proposal Computer

Comment: Cannot find "JavaScript Completion Proposal Computer" on Kepler Help

Comment: On this example categoryId not match proposalCategory id

Comment: Instead of this: try to add activate="true" in javaCompletionProposalComputer and remove <partition />

Comment: OK, that is to explorer `javaCompletionProposalComputer` options

Comment: It worked, add your answer if you like it to be accepted. Next thing for me will be 1) understanding context (that is to define where is client side and where is server side) 2)why there is no icon in In Preferences -> JavaScript -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced

Comment: As I saw in code, JSDT contain only one context now. You can register own and use it on additional computers. Icon is an another extension point in UI plugin. Look at my eclipse-extjs plugin ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as @zulus said:

> try to add activate="true" in javaCompletionProposalComputer and remove

what worked is:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
   id="nodeclispe_textual_proposals"
   name="Nodeclipse Text Proposals">
   <proposalCategory icon="icons/npm/npm.gif"/>
 </extension>
 <extension point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
   id="NodeclipseProposals"
   name="Nodeclipse Proposals">
   <javaCompletionProposalComputer
      class="org.nodeclipse.ui.contentassist.JSDTProposalComputer"
      categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.textual_proposals"
      activate="true">
   </javaCompletionProposalComputer>
 </extension>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

Comment: Where do I find the file to edit? I just recently started having this error for some reason. On Mars.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple example implementation implementing Pauls answer you may check out this tutorial: http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/2014/05/extending-jsdt-adding-your-own-content.html

Comment: SO is not for sharing links. Is this solution different?

Comment: sorry for sharing the link. I thought having a downloadable, running out of the box solution would be helpful, too. The provided link also shows a default class implementation along with needed plugin dependencies